# Try Catch, Async Await resulting a request timeout in the production

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, try-catch

Im new in Try and catch with Async and Await method, My Code is working in a localhost but it takes to long to succeed when i deploy the in the production resulting request Timeout. I wondering in my interpretation in async and await is right, having a lot of object in an array which is variable details. is there another to speed up the process? Im using Try and catch to prevent crashing the application. Thank you for the answer.

```
async function find_201(req, res, data, bus, checklist, x){
try{
    let data1 = JSON.stringify(data)
    //old damaged
    const old_damaged = x.filter(obj => obj.isDamaged === true);
    //new damaged 
    const new_damaged = x.filter(({id}) => data1.includes(id)); //getting empty array
    const a_details = x.filter((id) => !old_damaged.includes(id));
    const details = a_details.filter((id) => !new_damaged.includes(id));

    for(w of details){
        let part = w.part,
            position = w.position,
            company = w.company,
            busNumber = bus,
            _id = w.id,
            mile_age = w.mile_age,
            isDamaged = false;
        let author = {
            id: req.user._id,
            username: req.user.username,
            firstName: req.user.firstName,
            lastName: req.user.lastName,
            };
        let image = {contentType: 'image/png', data: 'none'};
        let date_now = new Date().addHours(8).toISOString();
        let detail = {part:part,id:_id, position:position, company:company,isDamaged:isDamaged, mile_age: mile_age, author:author, busNumber:busNumber,image:image, date_created: date_now};
        let id = {id: _id, busNumber: bus};

        let a = await Bus.findOneAndUpdate(id, detail)
            if(!a) throw createError(404, 'Invalid ID for finding 201 file')
        let found = await Trip.findById(req.session.trip)
            if(!found) throw createError(400, 'Trip session expired, Please re-login again!')
        let raw = await Raw_360.create(detail)
            if(!raw) throw createError(400, 'Details incomplete for RAW Data 360, Please try again!')
                found.start_360.push(raw)
                found.save();
    }
    return res.redirect('/trip/' + req.session.trip)
}catch(e){
    error_logs(e, req)
    req.flash('error', 'ERROR CODE ' + e.status + ' ' + ' MESSAGE '+ e.message )
    return res.redirect('back')
}
```

};

Comment: Is the timeout of the awaits or the loading of the script itself? Can you debug production (with logs for example) to see where it throws the error? Youll need a bit more information to figure out what part is failing.

Comment: Hi Emre Koc, previously i have code without aync, await and try catch its loading fast and never encountered request timeout what I'm thinking the cause of request timeout is this new code.

Comment: This looks like mongodb queries? Try not to use `findOneAndUpdate` if you actually want to update multiple items, not just one.